# How to create a pivot query in SQL Server with CASE Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Col1 contains only X and Y.

```
Col1    Col2

X       abc

Y       pqr

X       pqr

X       mnq

Y       cxr
```

I want to make it like this:

```
X    Y    Col2

Yes  Yes  pqr
Yes  No   abc
Yes  No   mnq
No   Yes  cxr
```

What SQL Query i should write?

Comment: I think this can be done using a PIVOT query: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution using the [SQL PIVOT operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT Col2, 
  case when X=0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end as X, 
  case when Y=0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end as Y
FROM MyTable
PIVOT (
  count(Col1)
  FOR Col1 IN ([X], [Y])
) AS PivotTable;
```

#### Running sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5856d/14

Comment: I've simplified the query by eliminating the sub-select

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
with cte as (select col2,
                    min(col1)as X,
                    min(col1) as Y,
                    count(distinct col1) as cnt
             from  your_table
             group by col2)
select COL2,
       case when X='X' then 'Yes'  else 'No' end X,
       case when Y='Y' OR  cnt=2 then 'Yes'  else 'No' end Y
from cte
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da3f9/2)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
select col2,CASE WHEN COUNT(*)=1 then CASE WHEN min(col1)='X' then 'YES' else 'NO' end  else 'YES' end as 'X',
            CASE WHEN COUNT(*)=1 then CASE WHEN min(col1)='Y' then 'YES' else 'NO' end else 'YES' end  as 'Y' 
from MyTable group by col2
```

Comment: How does this show how to create a pivot?  This shows how to use a case statement.

Comment: @user2676140, a pivot can be created using CASE statements. If you don't believe me, please see above! No reason to downvote this. No reason to upvote it either, since the built in PIVOT can do the job, although sometimes CASE statements work better.